# How to fix error "This function has a return type of Column, but doesn't end with a return statement"

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

working on a demo chat app, trying to return data from firestore. and am getting the error.

```
child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('messagees').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final messages = snapshot.data.documents;
              List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
              for (var message in messages) {
                final messageText = message.data['text'];
                final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
                final messageWidget =
                    Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
              }

              return Column(
                children: messageWidget,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
```

I do have a return statement, so shouldn't be getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not written return type widget if the snapshot has no data

```
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messagees').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final messages = snapshot.data.documents;
          List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
          for (var message in messages) {
            final messageText = message.data['text'];
            final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
            final messageWidget =
                Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
            messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
          }

          return Column(
            children: messageWidget,
          );
        }else{ // put this else block
          return Container(
             child: Text('No Data Found'),
          ),
         }
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The return statement only occurs if the (snapshot.hasData) is true.

It does not specify what is returned if the statement is false.

Suggestion: There could be a return statement after the "if-block" which returns null (or something) which will be met when the "if-statement" is false.

Then, on the receiving end of the returned value, check if the data is "null". If the data is not "null", then the received value is, indeed, a "Column".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this;

And if you have the log you can share?

```
static List<Text> messageWidgets = []; // out of build

child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('messagees').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final messages = snapshot.data.documents;
              for (var message in messages) {
                final messageText = message.data['text'];
                final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
                final messageWidget =
                    Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
              }

              return (messageWidget ==  null || messageWidget.isEmpty) ? Text("List is empty") : Column(
                children: messageWidget,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
```